# How to group object lifecycle together in Swift without a strong reference cycle?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

**Background**

I'm relatively new to Swift (coming from a C++ and C#) background, and I'm struggling with how best to design some of my data model types and interfaces. ARC seems great and makes certain things easier, but I find myself running into certain design challenges.

**Problem**

Suppose we'd like to represent some complicated, interconnected data with a mix of different objects (of classes A, B, and C). For example, say each A object should have an associated B object and multiple C objects. The A object must also respond to changes in its linked objects (eg. when a C object changes, the associated A must update its own internal state and notify its B too).

Due to ARC, we can't simply have these objects all strongly reference each other, otherwise we end up with a strong reference cycle (and memory leaks).

Fortunately Swift provides us with `weak` and `unowned` references, so we can always set up our relationships like this (*dashed lines are weak references*):

[image: Object relationships]

This is workable but can be somewhat cumbersome to set up, especially for lots of interconnected objects. It's even more cumbersome if we are using third-party classes (which we can only modify via extensions).

Also, if the main A object is only using weak references, it can't actually keep its associated B or C objects alive on its own.

Reversing the direction of our `weak` references will fix that particular problem, but it introduces its own drawbacks.

For example, suppose a view or controller only needs to interface with the C objects. However, if it only maintains references to these C objects, and those C objects only have weak references to the backing A object, that A object might be freed. This basically forces client code to keep a reference to the A object around to prevent the C objects it cares about from being orphaned.

**Wishful Thinking**

Ideally I wish to simply and easily tie the lifecycle of these objects together, but without producing a memory leak. In other words, I'd like to create an A object (which would then create its own associated B and C objects) and have them all keep each other alive, *but only as long as external code had at least one reference to any one of these "bundled" objects*.

Is this possible (and practical) in Swift?

**More Specifics**

I wasn't sure if the details would clarify or cloud things, but if it helps... one of the scenarios where I've run into this is modeling data and storing it with Core Data.

For example, A is the "public" programmer-friendly interface (conforming to a standardized data protocol), B is the "private" backing storage (a Core Data entity), and C is a helpful encapsulation of complicated data.

There are also some associated D & E classes I left out which are also associated with the main A object. These are themselves much like our A class here, ie. a public interface to data models with their own complicated multi-object relationships, but fundamentally suffer from the same issues as our A to C relationship.

In other words, client code might only need to interface with a D, but modifying the D on its own won't function correctly unless the associated A object is somehow kept alive too.

**Somewhat Tangential**

This makes me wonder how Core Data entities manage their relationships without introducing strong reference cycles. For example, you might have X, Y, and Z entities all relating to and relying on each other.

Based on the classes that are auto-generated, I don't see any weak references. How can these managed objects maintain references to each other without memory leaks?

Comment: “This basically forces client code to keep a reference to the A object around to prevent the C objects it cares about from being orphaned.” Not necessarily. If the view controller needs to interface with C objects, it would simply keep its own strong reference to the C objects.

Comment: This is one of those cases where discussing this in the abstract only clouds the issue, IMHO. Why don’t you give us a practical, real-world example of the sort of problem you’re concerned about.

Comment: I get that, and perhaps my wording is unclear. The C objects provide the interface, but if the A object they're associated with (and weakly reference) ends up getting freed in the meantime, they won't work as needed. I'll add some more details though.

Comment: If B keeps strong reference to C objects it needs, then when A is deallocated, the C objects won’t. But if you’re saying that that C cannot work at all without A, then the fundamental design may be problematic (separate classes should be as loosely coupled as possible). It depends. I really think this discussion would be more constructive if you could articulate practical example.

Comment: @Rob: C is a pretty simple, generic encapsulation of data that can be used in a wide variety of situations, so it doesn't normally depend on A to work. However, in order for its data changes to get stored (via the B object), the A object must also still exist.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible strategies you could use (there could be others) :

1) Embrace the strong reference cycles and dismantle it explicitly

2) Make the various classes autonomous by enabling them to dynamically instantiate their referenced objects as needed.

For #1, you could either require the calling code to call some "clean-up" method to break the strong references (e.g. methods of the A,B,C ... classes that set their strong references to nil).  Or, you could create a container class that instantiates the objects and hold the strong references and then let the calling code own that container.

For #2, the various classes would only need a hierarchical Strong-><-Weak relationship and "children" object would lazily re-instantiate their "parent" instance as needed (similar to CoreData faulting on ManagedObjects).

Comment: As I kind of already feared, it seems like these really are my main options currently... I hadn't really considered just "embracing the strong reference cycle" or creating some explicit cleanup methods, although I have plenty of experience doing just that in C++. It just seems out of place in Swift.

Comment: The ironic thing is my hypothetical A class sprung into existence partially because it seemed like I needed a container to maintain references to the various other instances and glue them all together. It just feels wrong forcing client code to have to "know" about the A (container) type when (in some cases) all it really needs are the individual C elements. It's simple enough to implement, I just don't like adding additional dependencies when they shouldn't really be necessary (IMO). I'm also already using your #2 idea to some extent, dynamically/lazily re-instantiating objects as needed.

Comment: This may just be semantics and a view of the mind but you could consider that these objects are managed by a "broker" (or internal server)  that the application needs to go through to obtain instances.   This would legitimize the container's existence while providing a consistent paradigm for the application.  A bit like having to go through a database server to get at tables.  You first get a connection (or session) and everything else has to be obtained through that object.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is a reasonably good example of how you'd want to attack this kind of problem. In Core Data there is a managed object context that actually owns all the objects. Managed objects are proxies which may in fact be faults.

Given your example (a backing store that is a managed object), you'd address this by storing the managed object ID rather than the object itself. When you want to access the underlying object, you ask the context for it, and it either returns you the existing objet or faults one into existence.

If you have your own (non Core Data) system, you can create a similar approach with `NSCache` and `NSDiscardableContent` that will keep objects around when they're being actively used, and purge them when they're not. You just need a mechanism for reinstantiating them when needed.

But the key is to work with IDs or proxies rather than the actual object, and hold onto the actual objects in a container that manages memory, just like Core Data.

Comment: Interesting and helpful thoughts, so thanks! Still I can't help but feel like I've found a weird "hole" in Swift and ARC's design, which are supposed to make memory & object lifecycle management easier. Granted in most cases they do (I vastly prefer Swift over C++), but here we are talking about creating a pretty complex object lifecycle/proxy/memory manager to address a relatively simple problem. Oh well...

Comment: It's not so much a hole as a choice. ARC (which long predates Swift) absolutely made memory management easier, but it made tradeoffs to be fast and predictable rather than easy. Before ARC, there was an attempt in OS X to introduce a garbage collector, which in principle would simplify this situation. It was incredibly unpopular and was removed. Many Android tears are shed over stutters due to the garbage collector. The trade-off for highly predictable performance and low high-water marks is extra developer work to manage memory. It's not the only sensible tradeoff, but it is Cocoa's.

Comment: As a rule, Swift is "closer to the metal" (more C++ like) than most other modern languages, with the exception of Rust. If you're interested in the future of Swift memory management, you should definitely pay attention to Rust. That's where most of the inspiration is coming these days, and we may very well see a replacement for ARC over the next few years. ARC solved a specific problem brilliantly (making Cocoa development easier, safer, and faster). Swift has grown out of Cocoa, but we should expect to become less and less tied to Cocoa patterns over the coming years.

Comment: I read a little about Rust recently, and I'm definitely curious to know more. Anyway, just to clarify, I wasn't saying the GC approach is superior to ARC (nor am I knowledgeable enough to even have a strong opinion). If anything, I (perhaps naively) believe Swift/ARC could be expanded relatively simply to accommodate bundling object lifecycles together. For example, objects explicitly bundled together (via some new type of reference) could maybe share a single reference counter. Once there were no remaining external references to any of the bundled objects, they would all be freed.

Comment: In the official Swift ARC reference page, even its examples highlight how useful shared reference counts might be. For example, we're forced to define either the `Apartment` or `Person` as the "weaker" relationship, when I see them as peers. Why should `Apartment`s have to depend on external code to keep their `tenant` (`Person`) alive? Similarly, if client code only has a reference to a `CreditCard`, and then it goes to access its `customer`, an access violation might occur! Perhaps it's because Swift is already so good, but these types of oversights seem kinda glaring to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading your problem and I keyed in on the following phrase, *“The A object must also respond to changes in its linked objects”*.

In Swift, properties are generally used to show ownership.

```
class A {
    let bee: Bee = Bee()
    let cees: [Cee] = [Cee(), Cee()]
}

class Bee {
}

class Cee {
}
```

Inter-instance communication can be done in a few ways.

**Delegation**

```
class A: BeeDelegate, CeeDelegate {
    let bee: Bee = Bee()
    let cees: [Cee] = [Cee(), Cee()]

    func beeDidChange(_ bee: Bee) {
    }

    func ceeDidChange(_ cee: Cee) {
    }

    init() {
        bee.delegate = self
        cees.forEach { $0.delegate = self }
    }
}

protocol BeeDelegate {
    func beeDidChange(_ bee: Bee)
}

class Bee {
    weak var delegate: BeeDelegate?
}

protocol CeeDelegate {
    func ceeDidChange(_ cee: Cee)
}

class Cee {
    weak var delegate: CeeDelegate?
}
```

**Notification**

Here is a partial Notification solution. All that’s needed is posting the change notifications from within `Bee` and `Cee`.

```
class A: BeeDelegate, CeeDelegate {
    let bee: Bee = Bee()
    let cees: [Cee] = [Cee(), Cee()]

    func beeDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    }

    func ceeDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    }

    var center = NotificationCenter.default

    init() {
        center.addObserver(forName: .beeDidChange, object: nil, queue: nil, using: beeDidChange)
        center.addObserver(forName: .ceeDidChange, object: nil, queue: nil, using: beeDidChange)
    }

    deinit() {
        center.removeObserver(self)
    }
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let beeDidChange = Notification.Name(rawValue:"BeeDidChange")
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let ceeDidChange = Notification.Name(rawValue:"CeeDidChange")
}
```

**KVO**

Key-Value Observing is a complex topic and is not easy to cover without all the details.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response. I am familiar with these forms of inter-instance communication, and I am more concerned with how to effectively "bundle" together the lifecycles of these related instances. Case in point, your delegate example suffers from one of the issues I first described. If client code only has a reference to `A.bee` (an instance of Bee), and nothing else keeps a reference to the original A object, Bee's delegate gets freed and Bee is left orphaned.

Comment: @Jeremy I see. Perhaps it's implicit designing around ref-only, perhaps it's practice vs. theory, but that is simply not an issue. `a` being let go means no other object cares enough about `a` to hold ownership. If `bee` needs an update from `a` based on changes to `bee`, then you have a dangerous loop. If one of the `cees` needs an update from `a` based on changes to `bee`, then you have side-effect side-effects which has horrible code smell. For systems that complex, it might be a good general principle to only hold the root object in the tree.